# Visual Studio Team Services: Release Management for layered infrastructure in an enviroment

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops, release-management, continuous-deployment

I am trying to configure release management using VSTS (release hub). My Applications are distributed across several zones per environment. I have two different zones, each zone is considered a different network.

- UI Applications  will be on zone 1  (for this purpose I created Build
  Definitions "UI Build Definition" for UI Projects)
- Service APIs on zone 2 (also created Different Build Definitions
     "ServiceAPI Build Definition)

Now, when new builds exits for each of them, I need to release each one to the corresponding Zone ( taking into consideration that the zones are different networks)

I am thinking that one agent will exist per zone to download the releases.

How to do the release management part? Configuration and specifying zones or servers  per environment,  link each release to a server in different zones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid there isn't any way to do this for now since you can only select one "Agent Queue" for one environment and there isn't any way to specify which Agent in the queue to use base on different networks.

The alternative way for this would like what you think in the comments: Use two pipeline: Dev(Zone1)->QA(Zone1)->Prod(Zone1) and Dev(Zone2)->QA(Zone2)->Prod(Zone2). With this, you can specify different agents for different zones.

Comment: Yes, this is what i have implemented.

Answer (score 0):

A specific Release in VSTS corresponds to a specific deployment pipeline, ie the route your application needs to take to become live (something like DEV > QA > PROD). A Release consists of Environments, and in each Environment you need to deploy the components of your application that must work together such that if you missed deploying a component your application world break. Think Unit of Work.

The specifics will depend on how you are doing your deployments. If you are copying artifacts to target nodes and then running PowerShell on that node to do the deployment then the agent needs to be able to see the node - typically using WinRM. If an agent can see all nodes in the different zones you only need one agent.

Comment: Yes, I have the environments Dev > QA > PROD. But in each environment I have 3 zones, where an agent can see the nodes in one zone only. if I use an environment as a zone, this not will be the real situation.

Comment: How about three linked environments to cope with the three zones, eg for DEV - DEV-Z1, DEV-Z2 and DEV-Z3? They can each have a different agent and be linked to run in sequence.

Comment: Thanks for you quick answers. If we are dealing with environments that means a release will be delployed on first ENV  then release it to the next stage in the pipeline. My problem is that each zone has different release, so there is no flow between the zones. Each one has different build definition. we can say that real situation is: release pipeline from Zone 1 in DEV Env to Zone1 in QA Env; another release pipeline would be Zone 2 in DEV to Zone 2 in QA, because there is the UI and Service Api releases.

Comment: Can you say more about the flow between the zones? I'm slightly confused as to what the actual problem is.

Comment: May be this link will clarify my point of view: [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/eeb55488-4fab-4239-874a-00157f099736/release-management-several-layers-envrioment-copy-specific-binaries-under-iis-directory-of?forum=TFService#eeb55488-4fab-4239-874a-00157f099736)

Comment: may be i have to make it flow on horizontal level not vertical as i was thinking, because the release flow from Zone 1 in dev to Zone 1 in QA ENV, not from Zone1 DEV to Zone 2 DEV ENV.